# how can I use 2 framebuffers (/dev/fbx), to display gui and video frame at same time using pygame?

Tags: debian, python3, pygame

I am working on zybo-7000 and Debian Jessie for my project. I have to make one window with GUI and in the same window, I have to make a small window for the video frame. (please see the picture)

I have 4 framebuffers. I am using 1 framebuffer only for displaying GUI (/dev/fb0), now I have to use other framebuffers to display different processed frames.

so far I came up with pygame to write GUI on framebuffers.

```
os.putenv("SDL_FBDEV", "/dev/fb0")
```

So currently, I am printing gui and video frame both using framebuffer 0. The refresh rate of gui is dependening on frame rate of video. If the video frame is lagging, it also slows down response rate of gui. Thus, I want to separate gui and video frame using separate framebuffer. Is there any instructions or method available in Python to separatly write gui and video frame in separate framebuffer. Please see the picture for better understanding.
I also tried looking in pyqt, but they said it is not possible to use multiple framebuffers from one qt application. here is the link (look at LinuxFB --> fb=/dev/fbN)
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html#

I am open to any suggestions. my project is here 
https://github.com/vivekpatel99/zybo_7k_object_tracking

(I think, if I use two framebuffers at the same time then a big window (fb0) will have a less refresh rate then small window(fb1/fb2/fb3) and I will have more resources for the image processing. that is my plan)
[image]

Comment: I am not so sure that this is how framebuffers are supposed to work. [Some information can be found here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98624/19575) There are things like the fbdev driver for X or even kdrive. Maybe these can help you. Plain X (no GTK, no Qt) isn't exactly bad. I once built a thin client from a 400Mhz 32MB MIPS based WiFi router with an USB 2.0 port...